# Checking the convergence of the improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, solution-verification

> So I have the following function to which i should check the convergence:
> $$\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\arctan(-e^{x})}{\sin(\frac{1}x{})}$$

I thought that one way to do it was with a comparison test. I thought that the values of the function $\arctan(-e^x)$ lie between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$.
Therefore:

$$
\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\arctan(-e^{x})}{\sin(\frac{1}x{})} \leq \int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{0}{\sin(\frac{1}{x})} \leq 0 
$$

And since the integral of $0$ converges than by comparison, our integral, which is smaller, must also converge.
Would this logic make any sense?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Annalisa

Comment: Would you expect it to converge? It seems like it should diverge and you could show this maybe by expanding sin(1/x) into a taylor series centered at infinity.

Comment: Based on the answer we got in the lecture, I think it should converge.

Comment: but the limit of the integrand as $x \rightarrow \infty$ does not converge (to anything, and certainly not to zero). Have you tried plotting your integrand on Desmos or Mathematica?

Comment: i think the limit goes towards  $- \infty$ , however i think there are cases when the integrand doesn't have a limit or goes towards infinity but the Integral nevertheless converges.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison test would say if $0 \le a(x) \le b(x)$ and $\int_1^\infty b(x)\; dx$ converges then so does $\int_1^\infty a(x)\; dx$.  But in this case $a(x) < 0$.

Comment: we have said in the lecture that a(x) can also be negative as long as its absolute value is positive. Would that be false?

Comment: In that case the comparison test would require $|a(x)| \le b(x)$.

Comment: i see..but could you help me with another possible approach?

Comment: As $x \to +\infty$, $\sin(1/x) \sim 1/x$ and $\arctan(-e^x) \to -\pi/2$...

Answer (score 0):

If you take into account @Robert Israel's comment
$$I_p=\int_{1}^{p} \frac{\arctan(-e^{x})}{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\,dx\sim -\frac \pi 2 \int_{1}^{p} x \,dx=-\frac \pi 4 (p^2-1)\tag 1$$ Pushing the expansion of
$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=x+\frac{1}{6 x}+\frac{7}{360 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$ you would get
$$I_p\sim -\frac{\pi  \left(360 p^4-353 p^2+120 p^2 \log (p)-7\right)}{1440 p^2} \tag 2$$